# Where is the P4API.NET source code?

Tags: perforce, p4api.net

I have a software project from 2010 where we integrated P4API.NET to communicate with Perforce servers. We used the source code instead of the binary then, since that gave us more flexibility. Right now I want to upgrade that project to the latest P4API.NET since we're having some compatibility issues, but I can't seem to find the source anywhere; on the Perforce website I can only find the binary version. Am I missing something or did they choose to make the source unavailable?

Regards,

Thom.

Answer (score 5):

P4API.NET is maintained in the Perforce Workshop:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4api-net/

You can sync the latest source from the Perforce server at workshop.perforce.com:1666:

http://workshop.perforce.com:8080/guest/perforce_software/p4api.net/

or download a version 2018.2 source ZIP from the FTP site:

ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r18.2/bin.ntx86/p4api.net-src.zip

Comment: P4API.NET is no longer maintained in the workshop; the last checkin there was in April 2016.  p4api.net-src.zip can still be found on ftp.

Comment: The source link is now dead, but there are more recent submits to the workshop. The download as zip link produces are 500 error though.